# Need to generate one column from 2 differenct tables depending on a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

The code basically works, but I need to generate the Layover_Description column based upon the Stop_Type column.  For Stop_Type='Layaover', Ineed the l.Layover_Description.  For Stop_Type='In-Servcie' I need to concatenate the On_Street and Cross_Street to create the equivalent of l.Layover_Description.  I left out the Comfort_Station_Table since it is not an issue.  I am using MS SQL.

```
SELECT DISTINCT w.Date_Stamp, w.Walking_Distance_Change_date, w.Layover_ID, w.Stop_Type, l.Layover_Description, w.Comfort_Station_Number, c.CS_Name, w.Walking_Distance, w.Layover_Time, w.Base_Route, w.Scheduling_Use, w.Exception_Flag, w.Override_Flag, w.Walking_Notes, w.TP_ID_NOTES

FROM dbo.Walking_Distance_Table w
LEFT JOIN dbo.Layover_Table l
     ON w.Stop_Type = 'Layover' AND w.Layover_ID = l.Layover_Stop_ID
LEFT JOIN dbo.Route_Stop_Table r
     ON w.Stop_Type = 'In-Service' AND w.Layover_ID = r.Stop_ID
LEFT JOIN dbo.Comfort_Station_Table c
     ON w.Comfort_Station_Number = c.CS_Number
```

Data:
Walking_Distance_Table (minus the unnecessary )

```
Layover_ID  Stop_Type   Layover_Description Comfort_Station_Number  CS_Name
230     In-Service  2nd Av & Seneca St  656         Starbucks
258     Layover     LENORA ST & 2ND AVE 765         Cristalla
263     Layover     LENORA ST & 1ST AVE 765         Cristalla
430     In-Service  3rd Ave & Pine St   243         McDonald's
430     In-Service  3rd Ave & Pine St   667         Westlake Mezz
455     In-Service  3rd & University    660         Starbucks
480     In-Service  3rd & Madison       661         Starbucks
```

Layover_Table  (minus the unnecessary )

```
Layover_Stop_ID Layover_Description
93006       NORTH BASE
21775       CENTRAL BASE & CENTRL ATLANT PKG
1402        S MAIN ST & 3RD AVE S BAY 3
1401        S MAIN ST & 4TH AVE S BAY 4
```

Route_Stop_Table

```
Stop_ID Route_Expand    Routes  Stop_Status Stop_Type   Bearing On_Street   Intersection    Cross_Street
250 Route1      111 ACT     Regular     S   2nd Ave     Far side    Bell St
260 Route4      121 ACT     Regular     S   2nd Ave     Far side    Lenora St
280 Route1      111 ACT     Regular     S   2nd Ave     Far side    Stewart St
300 Route4      121 ACT     Regular     S   2nd Ave     Far side    Pike St
320 Route1      111 ACT     Regular     S   2nd Ave     Far side    Seneca St
```

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick:

'''

```
SELECT DISTINCT w.Date_Stamp, w.Walking_Distance_Change_date, w.Layover_ID, w.Stop_Type, 
     CASE WHEN w.Stop_Type = 'Layover' THEN l.Layover_Description ELSE CONCAT( r.On_Street, ' & ', r.Cross_Street) END as Layover_Description , 
     w.Comfort_Station_Number, c.CS_Name, w.Walking_Distance, w.Layover_Time, w.Base_Route, w.Scheduling_Use, 
     w.Exception_Flag, w.Override_Flag, w.Walking_Notes, w.TP_ID_NOTES

FROM dbo.Walking_Distance_Table w
LEFT JOIN dbo.Layover_Table l
     ON w.Stop_Type = 'Layover' AND w.Layover_ID = l.Layover_Stop_ID
LEFT JOIN dbo.Route_Stop_Table r
     ON w.Stop_Type = 'In-Service' AND w.Layover_ID = r.Stop_ID
LEFT JOIN dbo.Comfort_Station_Table c
     ON w.Comfort_Station_Number = c.CS_Number
```

'''